# Does ElasticSearch's Java Client use REST API?

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Does the ElasticSearch Java client use the ES cluster's REST API behind the scenes? I'm wondering if it's possible to deploy an ES cluster via AWS ElasticBeanstalk which requires `.war`s. There's a method for deploying ES as a `.war` but it offers only the REST interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, ES's REST API is using the Java API internally (see [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/java-api/index.html)) so the Java client is not going through the REST API.

If you deployed ES is only providing the REST API, I guess you'll have to use it even from a Java app.

Comment: Thanks - any idea how the Java API is manifested? Some custom protocol over TCP? RMI?

Comment: According to this [code](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/blob/master/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/transport/netty/NettyTransport.java), it uses [Netty](https://netty.io/) and TCP